# ShouldPerformSegue Fires Twice

Tags: ios, swift

I have currently come across a weird problem. I have a storyboard which has  `viewController A` with a button. From that button, I have created a segue in storyboard to `viewController B`. When the button is clicked, a segue is fired.

The button is a Login button, so I need to validate the login details before the segue is performed.

In `ViewController A`, when the button is pressed, I have following code:

```
@IBAction func SignInButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    guard let email = username.text , username.text != "" else {
        return self.successLogin = false
    }
    guard let pass = password.text , password.text != "" else {
        return self.successLogin = false
    }

    AuthService.instance.loginUser(email: email, password: pass) { (success) in
        if success {
            self.successLogin = true
        } else {
            self.displayAlertView(title: USER_LOGIN_FAILED_TITLE, message: USER_LOGIN_FAILED_MESSAGE)
        }
    }

}

override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    if successLogin != true && identifier == "homeSegue" {
        self.displayAlertView(title: USER_LOGIN_FAILED_TITLE, message: USER_LOGIN_FAILED_MESSAGE)
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
}
```

But with this, the first click shows the alert in `shouldPerformSegue`, and then a second click allows the login.

Any suggestions would be helpful on how can I fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should perform the segue inside your `AuthService` success closure callback, you should also remove the unwind segue from the button, the button must only execute the login logic, if the login went well then the segue must be performed but not before

```
AuthService.instance.loginUser(email: email, password: pass) { (success) in
        if success {
            self.successLogin = true
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "homeSegue", sender: self)
        } else {
            self.displayAlertView(title: USER_LOGIN_FAILED_TITLE, message: USER_LOGIN_FAILED_MESSAGE)
        }
 }
```

should work now

Comment: Hi Reiner, Thanks for your comment i worked out what my issue was, i needed to create a segue from viewcontroller, for testing purpose i had created from button. So therefore when button was getting clicked it would perform the segue even if the user was not validated. and when the user was validated it would perform it twice.

Comment: Your welcome, glad to help you @chirag90 best regards and happy code

Answer (score 1):

1. You can run segue programmatically.

`performSegue(withIdentifier: "homeSegue", sender: self)`

2. If you need to perform custom logic, moreover postpone navigation, it is better to bind button to the action, and trigger segue you need from it.